# Encoding of window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, html, url, encoding, fragment-identifier

Does `window.location.hash` contain the encoded or decoded representation of the url part?

When I open the same url (`http://localhost/something/#%C3%BC` where `%C3%BC`translates to `ü`) in Firefox 3.5 and Internet Explorer 8, I get different values for `document.location.hash`:

- IE8: `#%C3%BC`
- FF3.5: `#ü`

Is there a way to get one variant in both browsers?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in Firefox as it decodes `location.hash` an extra time when it is accessed. For example, try this in Firefox:

```
location.hash = "#%30";
location.hash === "#0"; // This is wrong, it should be "#%30"
```

The only cross-browser solution is to just use `(location.href.split("#")[1] || "")` instead for getting the hash. Setting the hash using `location.hash` seems to work correctly for all browsers that support `location.hash` though.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the most reasonable solution.

Comment: This test returns `false` under Firefox 10.0.1 at least. I'm not sure when it changed but of course if you want to support older versions this is still the best advice.

Comment: What if the hash part itself contains a #? In this case the split method won't work.

Comment: thanks for your solution! just keep in mind that the output of location.hash has a leading "#" but location.href.split not..

Comment: @Christophe: Possible '#' in the hash itself ought to be encoded as '%23'. To be extra certain, you obviously can use `location.href.split('#').splice(1).join('#')`. In this case there's even no need to add `|| ""` because the result is an empty string if there's no hash in the first place.

Comment: @PekkaKlärck the second # should not be encoded, it is an authorized character in the hash part of the url.

Comment: "The only cross-browser solution is to just use (location.href.split("#")[1] || "")" I presume you meant `decodeURIComponent(location.href.split("#")[1] || ""))`, but this can fail in other cases e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/nsoaee4q/9/

Comment: If you want to use split, I think you should use `location.href.split("#",2)[1] || ""` to split just by the first #

Answer (score 6):

Answering to my own question, my current solution is to parse `window.location.href` instead of using `window.location.hash`, because the former is always (i.e. in every browser) url-encoded. Therefore the `decodeURIComponent` function *CMS* proposed can always be used safely. *YUI* does the same, therefore it can't be that wrong...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent), it will return `#ü` in all cases:

```
decodeURIComponent('#%C3%BC'); // #ü
decodeURIComponent('#ü'); // #ü
```

Try it out [here](http://jsbin.com/awile#%C3%BC).

Comment: Not a solution because:
`decodeURIComponent('%2540'); // %40 (IE)`
but
`decodeURIComponent('%40'); // @ (FF)`

Comment: Not really sure about what you mean, %2540 is the `%` character encoded (`%25`) and the non encoded `40` string, `decodeURIComponent('%40');` is @ in IE or Firefox... http://jsbin.com/esafe

Comment: Let's assume I wanted to use the hash for a search function and someone wants to search for `%40` (but not for `@`). Depending on his browser, I will get `#%2540` (IE) or `#%40` (FF) as `location.hash`. If I decode it then, I get different results in the different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my version of Firefox (3.5 on Linux), if I type "#%C3%BC" as a hash in the URL, the URL itself actually *transforms* to unicode with "#ü". But you have appeared to answered your own question -- in Firefox, the browser transforms entity escape codes in the URL, while in IE, it does not.

My advice is actually this: Instead of putting "#%C3%BC" in the URL at all, just use full unicode in your hashes and URLs. Is that an option? It should work fine in any modern browser.

Comment: No, it's not :(. Your Firefox (and mine too) is just pretending to use an `ü` character. In HTTP it always uses the percent-encoding. Move your mouse over that link: http://test/%C3%BC. The Firefox status bar shows an `ü` for some reason. But if you use an HTTP sniffer, you will find out, that it's submitting `%C3%BC`.
And basically, because I'm using that one in a HTTP redirect, I can not directly use unicode characters anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't depend on the encoding being ASCII v a unicode encoding?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to transfer unicode characters in HTTP without special preparation like the percent-encoding (because HTTP does not allow characters outside the ASCII range).