# Is javascript window.location crossbrowser?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, window-object

Is javascript code window.location functional in all new and old STANDARD POPULAR browsers?

Comment: As long as Javascript is turned on... :D

Comment: How old is old? I doubt it'll work in Mosaic...

Comment: That's a good point and I didn't wrote my question right, I meant all STANDARD POPULAR Browsers, which they aren't too many.

Comment: isn't keyword crossbrowser for that?

Comment: @EBAG: try putting asterisks on both ends of a word you want to stress and *this* is the result. CAPS ARE CONSIDERED YELLING

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`window.location`, which shares the same structure as `document.location` should be identical between modern browsers for the following properties:

- `hash` ([except in FireFox ~< 16.0 where there was a bug with encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703552/encoding-of-window-location-hash))
- `hostname`
- `href`
- `pathname`
- `port`
- `protocol`
- `search`
- `reload()`
- `replace()`

**Known Differences:**

- Only Webkit has `location.origin` at the time of writing.

Comment: related: window.location.origin is missing in ie10 for windows phone, was added to ie11 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn736066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: window.location.origin polyfill: 
    if (!window.location.origin) {
        window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
    }

Comment: Tx for the "location.origin". In fact IE gets all bezerk! ;-)

Comment: Not true for pathname.

Answer (score 16):

I can't say 'all old browsers' since it may not work in Netscape Navigator 0.9 but yeah this is in the standard and is very widely supported.

Comment: Indeed. JavaScript was first supported in [Netscape 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator#The_rise_of_Netscape).

Answer (score 2):

window.location works in all major browsers